# how to use interpolation inside another one in angular list tag

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngfor

I have tried to retrieve data to view from firebase. so i have an attribue in databse sizesofGroups_1,sizesofGroups_2 .... so want to get this attributes using a NgFor. i have tried this for little bit. now i want to way to use something like this. **{{std.sizesofGroups_{{item}} }}**

**here is the html**

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let std of stdlist | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 7, currentPage: p }; let i = index;">
               
                 <tr  class="table-striped"> 
                <td>{{std.registeredYear}}</td>
                <td>{{std.course}}</td>
                <td>{{std.groupName}}</td>
                <td>{{std.numberofGroups}}</td>
                <td>

                  <ul style="list-style-type:disc;" *ngFor="let item of createRange(std.numberofGroups);" >
                    <li >{{std.sizeofGroups_+(item)}}</li> //here is the error
                   
                   
                  </ul>  

                </td>
          
                   <td>
                    <a class="action-btn" style="color:rgb(36, 143, 192); cursor: pointer" (click)="onEdit(std)">
                      <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                    </a>
                    <a class="action-btn" style="color:lightcoral; cursor: pointer" (click)="onDelete(std.id)">
                      <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
                    </a>
                  </td>
              </tr>
            
          </ng-container>
```

**here is the ts**

```js
createRange(number){
      var items: number[] = [];
      for(var i = 1; i <= number; i++){
         items.push(i);
      }
      return items;
    }
```

here is the picture of DB
[image]

**what do i missing?**

Comment: You can may be create a variable inside ngFor: ``...;let size = item.length`` ?

Comment: How can it help to use {{std.sizesofGroups_{{item}} }} thing? 

Comment: can you create variable, let i = index in first ngFor and try this: ``{{(this['stdlist' + i])['sizeofGroups_' + item]}}`` in place of your interpolation ? will put this as an answer if it works.

Comment: Can you put your suggestion to my NgFor and give it as an answer. Then I can get an idea

Comment: Replace your interpolation with what I give: ``{{(this['stdlist' + i])['sizeofGroups_' + item]}}``

Comment: i did this.. not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
  <li >{{std['sizeofGroups_' + item]}}</li>
```

this way it worked :)